# Remove First Character and Add Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the [autoNumeric jQuery plugin](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) to place a dollar sign and a decimal into a a couple of text fields.
Now I want to add these two values, but I'm getting the NAN error because of the dollar sign that is placed in front of the number.

How do I remove the dollar sign (first character), add the values and place the total value into another field?

Sample HTML

```
<input type="text" id="value_one" /><br />
<input type="text" id="value_two" /><br />
<input type="text" id="total_value" /><br />
```

Sample jQuery

```
$("body").hover(function() {
    var a = +$('#value_one').val();
    var b = +$('#value_two').val();
    var total = a+b;
    $('#total_value').val(total);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaK35/217/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$("#totalme").click(function () {
    var a = $('#value_one').val();
    var b = $('#value_two').val();
    var fltA = Number(a.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
    var fltB = Number(b.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
    var total = fltA + fltB;
    $('#total_value').val(total);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="value_one" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="value_two" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="total_value" />
<br />
<button id="totalme">Total</button>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/vaK35/220/)